# is it possible to write a method to sort an array of objects with respect to a specific field?

Tags: arrays, oop, sorting, object

i mean is it possible to have a method that gets as its parameters an array of objects and another parameter which indicates which field of the objects we are using to sort the array ?

for example if the objects are contacts if we call sort(contacts , name) it would sort them with respect to name. if we call sort(contacts , number) it sorts them according to their numbers.
maybe by sending an String of the field we want !! something like :

```js
 class sorting {
   
   public static bubble_sort(Object[] array , String field){
     
     for(int i =0; i<array.length ; i++){
       
      if(array[i].field > array[i+1].field)
        swap(array ,i ,i+1);
     
   }
}
```

(preferably in java) (and please include examples of the solutions you give !)

Comment: The answer depends very much on the language. Can you be more precise about which language you are talking about? It seems that you want an answer for Java.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming this is Java:  yes, it is possible. You can use [reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/fieldValues.html) to get the field type and value and then compare them. It would not be a good idea. Much better to use [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(T[],%20java.util.Comparator)) with the existing sort method.

Answer (score 2):

A method that would work in pretty much any language is to pass in some kind of function object.

```
class sorting {
  public static bubble_sort(Object[] array, FunctionObject ordering) {
  for(int i =0; i<array.length ; i++){
    if(ordering(array[i+1], array[i]))
      swap(array ,i ,i+1);
  }
};
```

different languages are going to have different syntaxes for such a function object -- what its type is, etc -- but pretty much every language is going to have some way to do it.

Generally the best signature for it is one that takes two different objects, and returns true if the left one is less than the right one.

Similarly, different languages are going to have different ways of invoking a function object.  Some may require `ordering.Invoke( array[i+1], array[i] )`.

In that function object, compare the field in question.  If the language/objects have reflection, you can sometimes do this via field name directly.

As this pattern is very useful, languages tend to make it easier as they mature.  So the most recent version of your language may have a syntax to create such objects with far less syntax, and invoke them with less syntax as well.